# How Can I get input in arrays in C?

Tags: c

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <math.h>
    int main()
    {
        int numbers[5];
        printf("Enter your first number:%d");
        scanf("%d", numbers[0]);
        printf("Enter your second number:%d");
        scanf("%d", numbers[1]);
        numbers[3]=numbers[0]+numbers[1];
        printf("Your desired result is:%d",numbers[3]);
        return 0;
    }
```

I seem to find no problem in the code but it won't even let me input numbers in the array I declared

Comment: What do you mean by "won't let"? What is the exact behaviour? Your `printf`s have a few issues. They don't end in `\n` which means the output may not get printed immediately as stdout is line buffered. Perhaps that is what is confusing you. Add a trailing `\n` or call `fflush(stdout)`. Also the `%d` in the `printf` should not be there.

Comment: *I seem to find no problem in the code* But you have problems in the code. In `scanf`.

Comment: `numbers[0]` is an integer. The `"%d"` specifier requires a pointer, `&numbers[0]` as the argument. (same for `scanf()` with `&numbers[1]`) Also, you cannot use `scanf()` correctly unless you ***Validate The Return*** to determine whether a **Matching Failure** (or **Input Failure**) occurred. There is no need to include `math.h` in your code. Basic math operators, `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, etc.. are provided by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in the second argument of scanf.

```
scanf("%d", numbers[0]);
```

it expects an address of where to write your input to but you are passing the **value** of numbers[0]. So scanf will write to whatever is in numbers[0] which is an int, not a pointer.

Take the address of numbers[0] by changing it to:

```
scanf("%d", &numbers[0]);
```

Comment: It would also be nice to see `if (scanf ("%d", &numbers[0]) != 1) { /* handle error */ }` just to ensure the input was valid and not a slip tapping `'r'` while reaching for `'4'`.